# Internal 500 error: Activating rootio theme and deploying with capistrano

Tags: errors, 500-internal-error, theme-roots

When I deploy my wordpress site using Mark Jaquith's capistrano recipes, I get a 500 internal error when trying to activate my roots.io theme. All other default themes work.

Here are my server logs:

require_once(/www/*********.*********.*********/releases/20140116200222/wordpress): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/*********.*********.*********/releases/20140116200222/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots/functions.php on line 5, referer: http://*********.*********.*********/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php

[Thu Jan 16 20:05:34 2014] [error] [client *********] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /www/*********.*********.*********/releases/20140116200222/wordpress/wp-content/themes/roots/functions.php on line 5, referer: http://*********.*********.*********/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php

Here's my folder structure:

[image]

So far I've tried:

- Downgrading to 3.8 stable from 3.9 alpha
- Replacing my custom roots theme with a fresh unedited one
- Changing my httpd config to point to the actual path of the file, not just the symbolically linked folder 'current'
- Moving my roots theme from `content/themes/` to `wordpress/wp-content/themes/`

Any thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like there might be some legacy server paths in the database that are causing problems. You might want to check there first.

Comment: Please add the code from where the plugin/theme is trying to load the file. That's with a 99% chance the problem.